# multiple listing index in the loop in python

Tags: python, list

Below is my code which is finding a common element.

but I actually want to get the index of it as well, can someone tell me how to do that?

```
a1=[11,10,21,23,24,25,128,12]
b1=[1,2,11,12,21]
c=[]
index_a1=[]
index_b1=[]
for element in a1:
      if element in b1:
          c.append(element)
c
```

i want `index_b1(expected result)` like `[2,3,4]`, and `index_a1` as well if possible.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `enumerate()` and `list.index()`.

```py
for idx, element in enumerate(a1):
    if element in b1:
        c.append(element)
        index_a1.append(idx)
        index_b1.append(b1.index(element))
```